# How to press a button in a flexipage screen flow via API?

Tags: api, flexipages

I have a Screen Flow, which is used in a flexipage, with one selection and a button. I need this button to be "clicked" from another app, using the API. I don't want to refactor all the steps in this flow into a separate autolaunched flow. Also, ideally, I need the visibility rules on a flexipage to "work" (so that API call would fail if the screen is not visible).

Can I achieve this?

I've tried to start with `GET /services/data/v50/ui-api/actions/flexipage/<FLEXIPAGE_NAMES>` API, but I don't even know where to find my flexipage name (filename, `masterLabel`, `sobjectType` are not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API that you are using to get the actions is only for display and won't work to execute the action.

Note that the screen flows are meant only to be used in Salesforce user Interface either using Salesforce Web or Salesforce Mobile or Communities.

If you need to [invoke a flow via an API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_system_rest.htm&type=5) outside salesforce then the auto launched flow is the recommended approach.